# Making dynamic conditions in javascript, jquery or vue

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, validation, vue.js

Hi guys what if I have a array that has this kind of values?

```
$query = [true, "&&", false, "||" true];
```

is there any helper? or libraries to make this into a 1 boolean result based on the conditions given ofcourse. I'm just looking for ideas or libraries that might be able to do this so I don't waste my time building my own way. Thank you guys.

Comment: Hi there @keannu - just to let you know, your question is off topic for [so]. Please take some time to read over the relevant pages in the help center, specifically ["What topics can I ask about here"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). In essence, recommendation posts are not allowed since they are heavily opinion based.

Comment: [ask] !!! <----

Answer (score 1):

Eval is evil, but fastest solution:

```
$query = [true, "&&", false, "||", true];
eval($query.join(" "));
```

Comment: Hi, can I ask why it is evil?

Comment: A problem for the original question, but also for this answer: how to you distinguish between `(false && true) || true` and `false && (true || true)`?

Comment: I have researched it is there any other solution though?

Comment: The reason that people say "eval is evil" is because it is essentially executing arbitrary code that you might not know where it is coming from. It is not in itself evil - but it creates a situation where you may be executing code you are not aware of. Basically - it is very easy to create insecure code using `eval` - this is why people advise to stay away from it.

Comment: It's a javascript mantra, ask google better! ;-) Not always, perhaps you must check before the array items in order to check that are "safe", ensure that it's not user input....

Comment: @ScottSauyet using eval, you can add more items into array or modify the existing ones: ["(", true, "&&", false, ")", "||", true]; ["(true", "&&", "false)", "||", true];

Comment: So in order to use eval "safely" I just need to filter my array right?

Comment: @ScottSauyet I have also a (true || true)

Comment: `const $query = ['launch', '(', 'nuclearMissiles', ')']; eval($query.join(' '))` Oops!

Comment: well i'm only expecting true, false, || and && so I just need to filter if an value exists outside that choices then i will not execute will this be good enough though?

Comment: My point was that this can be ambiguous.  Do you associate to the left or the right?

Comment: what do you mean by "Do you associate to the left or the right?".
All I need is an output of true or false really based on a array of booleans and strings.

Comment: Boolean algebra: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra, Associative property: http://www.mathwarehouse.com/dictionary/A-words/definition-of-associative-property.php

Comment: Think of `4 + 3 * 5`.  `(4 + 3) * 5 //=> 7 * 5 => 35` associates to the left.  `4 + (3 * 5) //=> 4 + 15 => 19` associates to the right.   My first comment shows how this is also ambiguous when faced with `false && true || true`.

Comment: Actually a user makes this array. we have 3 types of input.
1 is a statement which takes Value ==Value?
2 is a condition which takes || and &&
3 a group statement which creates (value == value || value == value) *Can also be and*

Comment: Then it will have array of true || true and (condition)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there are any libraries exactly for this purpose. So as an idea

`eval($query.join(' '))` should work, at the other hand, this is not good at all, because `eval` is *evil*

If you would ask me, then maybe I would go for a custom solution like:

```
conditions = [
  ctx => ctx.isThisSet,
  ctx => ctx.andThisAlsoIsSet
]

conditions.every(c => c(someGlobalCtx)) // => true | false
```

At the other hand, there are some libraries which are doing something like this but their are heavy and you have to study the docs first: like https://www.npmjs.com/package/logic-query-parser